HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
Can somebody tell me why am I having this issue while running pnpm run build. This is a Next.js project.
My package.json:
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@icons-pack/react-simple-icons": "^9.5.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss": "4.0.0-alpha.13",
    "@types/node": "20.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.19",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.1.3",
    "@vercel/speed-insights": "^1.0.9",
    "framer-motion": "^11.2.10",
    "geist": "^1.3.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.394.0",
    "next": "14.2.0-canary.62",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^4.4.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "rehype-pretty-code": "^0.13.2",
    "remark-gfm": "3.0.1",
    "shiki": "^1.6.4",
    "sugar-high": "^0.6.0",
    "tailwindcss": "4.0.0-alpha.13",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  }
}

Error I'm having while running the build script. Dev script is working fine.
Creating an optimized production build ...
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:312635)
    at /Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:106060
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28858), <anonymous>:44:1)
-- inner error --
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at /Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/static/css/fab7be39e746a489.css:2:32011
    at Parser.attribute (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:79568)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:93417)
    at Parser.loop (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:93089)
    at new Parser (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:79163)
    at Processor._root (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:96105)
    at Processor._runSync (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:96612)
    at Processor.processSync (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:97367)
    at /Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:36530
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
    at ensureCompatibility (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:35918)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at /Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/static/css/fab7be39e746a489.css:2:32011
    at Parser.attribute (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:79568)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:93417)
    at Parser.loop (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:93089)
    at new Parser (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:79163)
    at Processor._root (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:96105)
    at Processor._runSync (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:96612)
    at Processor.processSync (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:97367)
    at /Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:36530
    at Array.every (<anonymous>)
    at ensureCompatibility (/Users/sintuboro/Desktop/boroblog/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.0-canary.62_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:190:35918)


> Build failed because of webpack errors

I have gone through all the directories to see what I'm missing but doesn't look like any of my project files has issues. Not sure why the build is not working.

I found the fix! The issue was with the CSS:
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  code[data-theme*=" "],
  code[data-theme*=" "] span {
    color: var(--shiki-light);
    background-color: var(--shiki-light-bg);
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  code[data-theme*=" "],
  code[data-theme*=" "] span {
    color: var(--shiki-dark);
    background-color: var(--shiki-dark-bg);
  }
}

as detailed in this rehype-pretty-code blog post.
However, the correct CSS should be:
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  pre code[data-theme],
  pre code[data-theme] span {
    color: var(--shiki-dark);
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  pre code[data-theme],
  pre code[data-theme] span {
    color: var(--shiki-light);
  }
}

This change ensures that the correct theme is applied based on the user's color scheme preference without next build error.
